# Expected str instance, BoundField found (Django)

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

- Django version: 2.0
- python: 3.7
- jquery : 3.3.1
- bootstrap: 3.3.7

I am implementing ajax to my django forms. For that I was following [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html) tutorial. However I am getting a strange error when I click new book button or update button.

**"Expected str instance, BoundField found"**

Instead of opening a modal, only a small line is displayed.

[image]

**Full traceback**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/book/create/

Django Version: 2.1.2
Python Version: 3.7.2
Installed Applications:
['users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap_modal_forms',
 'main',
 'first_app',
 'campaign',
 'invoice',
 'taggit',
 'taggit_selectize',
 'rest_framework',
 'django_filters',
 'django_extensions',
 'shop',
 'search',
 'cart',
 'orders',
 'widget_tweaks']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Crowdsocial\templates\partial_book_form.html, error at line 3
   sequence item 7: expected str instance, BoundField found
   1 : {% load widget_tweaks %}
   2 : 
   3 :  {% for field in form %} 
   4 :   <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
   5 :     <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
   6 :     {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
   7 :     {% for error in field.errors %}
   8 :       <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
   9 :     {% endfor %}
   10 :   </div>
   11 : {% endfor %}
   12 : 

Traceback:

File "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Crowdsocial\users\views.py" in create_book
  194.     return save_book_form(request, form, 'partial_book_create.html')

File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Crowdsocial\users\views.py" in save_book_form
  178.     data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)

File "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  188.             return template.render(context)

File "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  173.                 return self._render(context)

File "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File
```

"C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  216.         return mark_safe(''.join(nodelist))

Exception Type: TypeError at /users/book/create/
Exception Value: sequence item 7: expected str instance, BoundField found

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('book_list/', views.book_list, name='book_list'),
    path('book/create/', views.create_book, name='book_create'),
    path('<int:pk>/book/update/', views.book_update, name='book_update'),
    path('<int:pk>/book/delete/', views.book_delete, name='book_delete'),
]
```

**form.py**

```
class EducationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Education

        fields = ['degree','school','edu_start_date','edu_end_date']
```

**Views**

```
def save_book_form(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            books = Education.objects.all()
            data['html_book_list'] = render_to_string('profile_settings.html', request, {
                'books': books
            })
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)

def create_book(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EducationForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = EducationForm()
    return save_book_form(request, form, 'partial_book_create.html')

def book_list(request):
    books = Education.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'book_list.html', {'books': books})
```

**Templates**

**partial_book_form.html**

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% for field in form %}
  <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
    <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
    {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**book_list.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block javascript %}
  <script src="{% static 'books/js/books.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1 class="page-header">Books</h1>

  <p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-create-book" data-url="{% url 'users:book_create' %}">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      New book
    </button>
  </p>

  <table class="table" id="book-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Degree</th>
        <th>School</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>End date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% include 'partial_book_list.html' %}
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-book">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**partial_book_create.html**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'users:book_create' %}" class="js-book-create-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Create a new book</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {% include 'partial_book_form.html' %}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create book</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**partial_update_form.html**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'users:book_update' form.instance.pk %}" class="js-book-update-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Update book</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {% include 'partial_book_form.html' %}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update book</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it by updating django-widget-tweaks library.

https://pypi.org/project/django-widgets-improved/

Comment: Updated [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks) and it works too

Comment: It happened to me while updating from django 1.11 to 2.0. I updated to django-widget-tweaks version 1.4.5 (released after the post was created) and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been trying to make the popup work for few days until I came across this solution. I tried it and it worked.